# Why was my flag declined while the question was closed for the flag reason?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, flagging

I flagged [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473144/how-to-get-good-accuracy-of-a-linear-regression-model-having-very-few-observatio) as "*needs details or clarity*"; my flag was declined, while the question was closed as such.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a side-effect of leaving the question open, which will decline the flag.

Following the [timeline](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/473144/timeline):

1. At 11:27:21 UTC, there was an initial vote to close *as a duplicate* to [How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222179)
2. Either before or after this, you flagged the question as "needs details or clarity".
3. At 11:50:45 UTC, [the review item](https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/close/265576) was created, garnering another close vote, then a binding *leave open* by a moderator. *This action declined your flag.*
4. At 13:59:54 UTC, the moderator then voted to close as "needs details or clarity"

Considering [the moderator's comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/873663),

> I think the question needs more detail before we can tell if it is a duplicate or not.

I think the moderator was worried if the question would still be closed as a duplicate instead of "needs details or clarity". Possibly a confusion, but I believe there was no harmful intent.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Still, the comment "*the question needs more detail before we can tell if it is a duplicate or not*" by a moderator does not fit rejecting a flag for the same reason. especially since mods are in no way obliged to act on a flag "now", and they can always wait.

Comment: @desertnaut I can't guess the real reason behind the mod's action. This answer just tries to explain that your flag was not directly rejected by the mod, but instead automatically declined by the system. The mod might not even realize your flag when choosing "leave open" from the review queue. Might also note that [the mod is very active and also the top reviewer on the close vote reviews](https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats)

Comment: OK, you are right - didn't look closely to your #3. Makes sense, accepting...